# Parse.com CloudCode does the codes after response.success() get processed?

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, parse-platform, promise

if I have a code like this

```
if (request.params.friends != null)
{
_.each(request.params.friends, function(friend) {
        // create news
        var News = Parse.Object.extend("News");
        var news = new News();

        news.set("type", "ask");

        news.save();
});
response.success();
}
```

and the length of `request.params.friends` is 2, does the second news get saved for certain? If not, how to make sure it gets saved? I looked at `Parse.Promise` documentation and in all the examples, the loop is inside a query or a save. Do I need to save the first news first and then create the `Promise`? I still don't get how "asynchronous" works.. Does the `response.success()` work like a `return` or `break`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop does get executed twice.
response.success() acts like a return.

The asynchronous magic is in the "save" method. When "save" is called, the Parse.com says, "ok, you want me to save it. I'll save it, but not now. For now, here is a promise that I'll save it later."  The save method returns an Promise object and the promise will be fulfilled when the object is actually saved.

So what happens is a little like

1. First time through the loop: create friend #1.
2. Ask Parse to save friend #1.
3. Second time through the loop: create friend #2.
4. Ask Parse to save friend #2.
5. Return successful response.
6. Parse actually saves friend #1 and friend #2

It's been a while since I've used Parse, but I'm not sure usually both the friend objects would actually get saves. Calling response.success() could kill work-in-progress. Here is an alternative implementation:

```
var objectsToSave = _.collect(request.params.friends, function(friend) {
        var news = new News();
        news.set({type : "ask"});
        return news;
});

Parse.Object.saveAll(objectsToSave, {
    success: function(list) {
      // All the objects were saved.
      response.success();
    },
    error: function(error) {
      // An error occurred while saving one of the objects.
    },
  });
```

The saveAll function saves all the objects at once. It's usually faster than saving objects one-at-a-time. In addition to providing saveAll with the objects to save, we provide it an object with a success function and an error function. Parse.com promises only to call the functions AFTER the save is complete (or it experienced an error).

There are a few other things going on. The Parse.Object.extend statement belongs in a different place in your code. Also, the set function doesn't take a list of strings. It takes a JavaScript object.

Comment: wow! great answer! thx @ahoffer! I guess I should check all my CloudCode functions for this kind of bug then

Comment: `Parse.Object.set()` works with `set("key", value)` as well as `set({key: value, key2: value})` http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#set